# How do I make a rectangle that's hollow on one side in javafx

Tags: javafx, shapes

Currently I'm using Netbeans 6.8 (a very old version of Netbeans).

As I said in the question, I would like to make a rectangle that's hollow on one side.

[image]

```
 Rectangle { 
      x: 150, y: 90
      width: 135, height: 35
      fill: Color.web("#209939")
      stroke: Color.GREY
 }
```

This is the code I use for the rectangle, quite simple. I've thought of using a circle and putting the circle over the rectangle, but that won't work with the other parts of the thing I'm programming. Really hope you can help me out!

Comment: Don't use JavaFX Script and JavaFX 1.x, it is obsolete.  Use an up-to-date version, currently [Java 9](https://www.oracle.com/java/java9.html).  Follow the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/get_start_apps.htm) to learn how to learn how to program the version of JavaFX included in the more recent Java distributions.

Comment: Then look at `javafx.scene.shape.Path`.

Comment: An up-to-date version would definetely be better, but (unfortunately) my teacher has only a lesson programm for this version of Java. So, I have to use this version for now.